# How to iterate correctly over a pixel access object from PIL?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have an image with some elements on it, placed horizontally. I want to find the widest image of them and create a box that can hold all of them. My idea is to try and find each elements width through columns and rows. When I try to iterate over the pixel access object I get from the image with im.load() I get an IndexError: image index out of range. I can't figure out what am I doing wrong.

This is an example image.
[image]

```
for row in xrange(height):
    for column in xrange(width):
            if pixel_array[row, column][3] != 0:
                width_boundaries.append((row, column))
                row += 1
                column = 0
```

Comment: How many channels does your image have? An RGBA image will have a fourth channel, but RGB won't. (and remember, `myList[3]` accesses the fourth element in a sequence)

Comment: Also: Where does PIL come into play here?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, valid example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: e.g. how are height and width calculated and what is pixel_array exactly.

Answer (score 0):

While iterating through a pixel access object each pixel position in object is referenced as (column, row). E.g., `pixel_map[596, 1023]` references a pixel in the 596th Column in 1023rd row.

The example below prints percentage of black pixels in every column of the image:

```
input_image = Image.open('Image.png').convert('L')
pixel_map = input_image.load()

for i in range(width):
    for j in range(height):
      if pixel_map[i,j]==0:
        zeroCnt=zeroCnt+1
    perc = zeroCnt*100 / height
    print(i,j,zeroCnt,perc)
```